# C# Calculator, Equals button repeat operation not working properly

Tags: c#, button, calculator, equals

I'm building a simple C# calculator and I am having some trouble with the equals button. The first click to calculate the specified equation works fine, but I want the operation to be repeated with the second number (y in this case) each time the user keeps clicking the equals button. Currently, the operation is repeated with the total of the operation, not the original second number. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is the class:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace BMW_CALC_UI
   {
    public class Calculator
    {
        public double Add(double x, double y)
        {
            // Addition
            return x + y;
        }

        public double Subtract(double x, double y)
        {
            // Subtraction
            return x - y;
        }

        public double Multiply(double x, double y)
        {
            // Multiplication
            return x * y;
        }

        public double Divide(double x, double y)
        {
            // Division
            return x / y;
        }

        public double SquareRoot(double x)
        {
            // Square Root (must be called as a double)
            return Math.Sqrt(x);
        }

        public double Reciprocal(double x)
        {
            // Reciprocal
            return 1 / x;
        }

        public double ChangeSign(double x)
        {
            // Change sign
            return -x;
        }
    }
    }
```

And here is the form:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BMW_CALC_UI
{
public partial class frmCalculator : Form
{
    public frmCalculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Set variables
    double x;
    double y;
    char operation;


    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDisplay.Text != "")
        {


            // Instantiate the instance
            Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();

            // Store second number
           if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out y))

            switch (operation)
            {
                case '+':
                    // Add addition method
                    txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Add(x, y)).ToString();
                    break;

                case '-':
                    // Add subtraction method
                    txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Subtract(x, y)).ToString();
                    break;

                case '*':
                    // Add multiplication method
                    txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Multiply(x, y)).ToString();
                    break;

                case '/':
                    if (y == 0)
                    {
                        // Display error message
                        txtDisplay.Text = "Cannot divide by zero";
                        return;
                    }
                    // Add division method
                    txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Divide(x, y)).ToString();
                    break;
            }

            // Reset 
            x = y;
        }                        

    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear all data
        txtDisplay.Clear();
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

            // Clear last number entered
            if (txtDisplay.Text != "" && txtDisplay.TextLength > 0)
            {
                txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text.Remove(txtDisplay.TextLength - 1);
            }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store first number, operation, then clear textbox
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            operation = '+';
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store first number, operation, then clear textbox
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            operation = '-';
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store first number, operation, then clear textbox
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            operation = '*';
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store first number, operation, then clear textbox
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
        operation = '/';
        txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void btnSquareRoot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        // Instantiate the instance
        Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();

        // Perform square root operation
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.SquareRoot(x)).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnReciprocal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        // Instantiate the instance
        Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();

        // Perform reciprocal operation
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Reciprocal(x)).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnSign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        // Instantiate the instance
        Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();

        // Perform sign operation
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.ChangeSign(x)).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnDecimalPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        // Add decimal point if none exist
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + ".";
        }
    }

    private void btnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        // If textbox starts doesn't start with 0 or Textbox
        // contains a decimal point then it is ok to add a zero
        else if (!txtDisplay.Text.StartsWith("0") || txtDisplay.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            // Add 0 to display
            txtDisplay.Text += "0";
        }
    }

    private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 1 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "1";
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 4 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "4";
    }

    private void btnSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 7 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "7";
    }

    private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 2 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "2";
    }

    private void btnFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 5 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "5";
    }

    private void btnEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 8 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "8";
    }

    private void btnThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 3 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "3";
    }

    private void btnSix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 6 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "6";
    }

    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 9 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "9";
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: You need to add the code that call this functions. I guess the problem is there

Comment: Form code posted, didn't make it through the first time, thanks!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. How can I store the second number differently? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you take the second number from the same text box you store the output

Here you take the second:
`if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out y))`

Here you store the output :
`txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Add(x, y)).ToString();`

Just store the result in other place, for example you can define "result" where you defined x,y.
store there the result.

And write in the "equals" function :

```
case '+':
// Add addition method
txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Add(result, y)).ToString();
break;
```

Of course if this is the first time you add numbers, you need to know it (store in some boolean)

Comment: Would this require a separate switch statement then? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, the code below is what I ended up with, which works well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BMW_CALC_UI
{
public partial class frmCalculator : Form
{
    public frmCalculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Set variables
    double x;
    double y;
    char operation;
    bool EqualsRepeated = false;

    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtDisplay.Text != "")
        {

            // Instantiate the instance
            Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();

            // Store second number
            if (EqualsRepeated == false)
            {
                if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out y))

                    switch (operation)
                    {
                        case '+':
                            // Add addition method
                            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Add(x, y)).ToString();
                            break;

                        case '-':
                            // Add subtraction method
                            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Subtract(x, y)).ToString();
                            break;

                        case '*':
                            // Add multiplication method
                            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Multiply(x, y)).ToString();
                            break;

                        case '/':
                            if (y == 0)
                            {
                                // Display error message
                                txtDisplay.Text = "Cannot divide by zero";
                                return;
                            }
                            // Add division method
                            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Divide(x, y)).ToString();
                            break;                   
                    }
                // Set button clicked to true
                EqualsRepeated = true;               
            }

            else
            {
                // If equals has already been clicked
                if (EqualsRepeated == true)

                    if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))

                    switch (operation)
                    {
                        case '+':
                            // Add addition method
                            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Add(x, y)).ToString();
                            break;

                        case '-':
                            // Add subtraction method
                            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Subtract(x, y)).ToString();
                            break;

                        case '*':
                            // Add multiplication method
                            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Multiply(x, y)).ToString();
                            break;

                        case '/':
                            if (y == 0)
                            {
                                // Display error message
                                txtDisplay.Text = "Cannot divide by zero";
                                return;
                            }
                            // Add division method
                            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Divide(x, y)).ToString();
                            break;
                    }
            }

        }                        

    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear all data
        txtDisplay.Clear();
        EqualsRepeated = false;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

            // Clear last number entered
            if (txtDisplay.Text != "" && txtDisplay.TextLength > 0)
            {
                txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text.Remove(txtDisplay.TextLength - 1);
            }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store first number, operation, then clear textbox
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            operation = '+';
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store first number, operation, then clear textbox
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            operation = '-';
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store first number, operation, then clear textbox
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            operation = '*';
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store first number, operation, then clear textbox
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
        operation = '/';
        txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void btnSquareRoot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        // Instantiate the instance
        Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();

        // Perform square root operation
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.SquareRoot(x)).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnReciprocal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        // Instantiate the instance
        Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();

        // Perform reciprocal operation
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.Reciprocal(x)).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnSign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        // Instantiate the instance
        Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();

        // Perform sign operation
        if (double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text, out x))
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = (myCalculator.ChangeSign(x)).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnDecimalPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        // Add decimal point if none exist
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + ".";
        }
    }

    private void btnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        // If textbox starts doesn't start with 0 or Textbox
        // contains a decimal point then it is ok to add a zero
        else if (!txtDisplay.Text.StartsWith("0") || txtDisplay.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            // Add 0 to display
            txtDisplay.Text += "0";
        }
    }

    private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 1 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "1";
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 4 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "4";
    }

    private void btnSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 7 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "7";
    }

    private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 2 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "2";
    }

    private void btnFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 5 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "5";
    }

    private void btnEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 8 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "8";
    }

    private void btnThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 3 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "3";
    }

    private void btnSix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 6 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "6";
    }

    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear display if error message is present
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("Cannot divide by zero"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }
        // Add 9 to display
        txtDisplay.Text += "9";
    }   
 }
 }
```